# How to block all internet traffic if not connected to specific VPN?

Tags: windows, vpn, connection

how can I block all internet traffic of my Windows 7 x64 computer if my VPN connection is lost ? Then, how to reconnect to it automatically ? Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally found "VPNCheck" and "VPN LifeGuard".

Comment: VPN LifeGuard is not in English. :(

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and figured out a way using the Win 7 / Vista firewall to block traffic if the VPN disconnects. Worked perfectly for me.

See: http://practicalrambler.blogspot.com/2011/01/windows-7-firewall-how-to-always-use.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: pramble: please expand your answer - such as that your reply will still be useful if the link dies. Thanks!