# How to prevent Internet acees if SwitchVPN is not running

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-vista, vpn, encryption

I've got a VPN Client (Switch VPN) that automatically starts on Windows login, but requires administratives elevations. As I am the owner of the computer (I share my PC with 2 other persons), I would like to make sure that every single connection to the Internet are encrypted with my VPN software.

Of course I know that VPNs clients doesn't make you truly anonymous but that's not my goal, my goals are to ensure that the Internet connection becomes more secure because of the encryption and that websites stop tracking me with the geolocalisation.

So, the problem is that I am the only user with an admin account and the 2 others users have an normal user account. I gave them the admin password so that they can activate SwitchVPN, but one of the user doesn't seem to do this even though I kindly asked him a thousand of time to do so.

My question is then: how can you prevent the PC (it's a dekstop computer btw) from having access to the Internet as long as the VPN software is not running? (the application has not started)

Congiguration system:
OS: Microsoft Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bits
Version 6.0.6002 SP2 Build 6002
SwitchVPN CLient

Comment: There isn't anything out of the box that would allow for this.  Some VPN clients can be configured to kill a process if its running but not connected.  Can you simply use a VPN client that does not require UAC prompt instead?

Comment: I would like to, but I have a subscription on their server, but I also got th econfiguration files, maybe I will be able to use them into another VPN Client?

Comment: [related](http://superuser.com/questions/195359/how-to-block-all-internet-traffic-if-not-connected-to-specific-vpn).  If their client does not offer this feature you will find it tough to do this.

Comment: well they do, but only once the application is started, but i would like to disconnect the Internet if the application hasn't started. I've seen somewhere that this could be achieved with the Windows Task Manager or so, but I really can't find it back

Comment: or with the Windows Firewall as explained here: http://practicalrambler.blogspot.be/2011/05/how-to-block-all-internet-traffic.html
I will try this out

Comment: Use the windows firewall to block all outgoing traffic unless it's through your tunnel.

Comment: There are [solutions](http://superuser.com/questions/456046/how-to-safeguard-pptp-connection-windows-7) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/557367/how-to-ensure-internet-access-is-only-via-vpn?rq=1)